# DateTime? to string yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, datetime, formatting

I have a method that takes a parameter of the type `DateTime?`

I need to convert what I receive to a string of the format - `yyyy-mm-dd`

What is the cleanest optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: `datetime.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `dateParameter` if of type `DateTime`, just like you said:

```
dateParameter.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

**EDIT:**

Since you edited your post to **nullable** `DateTime`, here's an edit:

```
dateParameter.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: its DateTime? .... and your answer doesn't work if its nullable DateTime

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) ..below is the sample code :-

```
datePassed.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

And for nullable DateTime :-

```
datePassed.Value.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

Comment: Why would he do `DateTime.ParseExact` if he accepts a parameter of `DateTime`?  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: ok I did not know it about the upodate @B.K.